# How to bulk import as user defined formatted data and stores as a varbinary(max) in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I wanted to select from couple of tables and need output as delimiter separated and stores this data into a table field which is declared as varbinary(max).

```
2018    | abc   | 2019-08-29
2018    | aab   | 2019-08-29
201907  | aab   | 2019-08-29
```

required output format

```
2018;abc;2019-08-29
2018;aab;2019-08-29
2019;aac;2019-08-29
```

Which I wanted to insert as a varbinary(max) field in to the database.How can I achieve it. Please suggest me a solution for this. Any tool which helps to bulk insert?

Comment: Why would you want to store delimited data in a table? What's wrong with the data as it is now, where it's readable and usable by your RDBMS? I can understand you would want to save a **file** in that format, but you certainly wouldn't want to store the values like that in your database. (Also asking for a tool to do this is off topic for SO).

Comment: The data is coming from another database. I wanted to store that into my db as varbinary

Comment: `'2018;abc;2019-08-29'` isn't a `varbinary` though. This looks like it could be the start of an XY Problem.

Comment: Looks like multiple [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There are many tools that can be used for ETL and for bulk inserting. Yet most of this discussion revolves around converting from one representation to a different representation. So what is your actual question? Is it about tools or how to combine multiple fields/columns into one column in a select statement?

Comment: I have a requirement to data transfer from one db to another db. I try to get the data in comma separated format (Such as nvarchar(max) ) and convert this data into varbinary(max) and stored into target table.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you can achieve your expected format:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(ColumnName1, 4), ';', ColumnName2, ';', ColumnName3)
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
SELECT LEFT(Column1, 4)+ ';'+ Column2+ ';'+Column3
```

Comment: `||` isn't valid T-SQL; it uses `+`.